# NoReverseMatch error in Django Tutorial part 4

Tags: python, django

This refers to the django 1.6 tutorial.

I keep getting this error message when I try to open the /polls/1/ page in part 4 of the tutorial:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<poll_id>\\d+)/vote/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://*/polls/1/
Django Version: 1.6.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<poll_id>\\d+)/vote/$']
Exception Location: /home/iamal/lib/python2.7/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 452
Python Executable:  /package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/iamal/tutorial',
 '/home/iamal/bin',
 '/home/iamal/lib/python2.7/Django-1.6.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/iamal/lib/python2.7/gunicorn-19.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python27.zip',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/package/host/localhost/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/iamal/lib/python2.7']
Server time:    So, 11 Jan 2015 00:03:43 +0100
```

I noticed that there seems to be no argument to be passed in the error message. When I replaced `poll.id` from line 5 in the details.html with `'1'`, it works. I have also checked that I included `namespace="polls"` in the project/urls.py file which seems to have been a common issue.

My details.html:

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

My polls/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from polls.models import Poll, Choice

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': poll_id})

def results(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'poll': poll})

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Comment: You're probably not passing the poll object to the template properly. You should show your view. (And please post the code here, rather than in a pastebin.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your detail view is passing the poll_id to the template target instead of the poll object itself. It should be:

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
```